# Azure AD V1.0 calling refresh token missing signature

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to get the id_token from Azure AD whit refresh token but when I am getting it. it`s missing signature and lots of data.

We have a .Net application and a Java Springboot application and they talk to each other through API. For authentication, we send the Azure ID token as Berear. The problem is the token expires after 1 hour and the user does not want to reload the page to refresh the token inside the .Net application.

I have tried to add a refresh token in the background but the token I`m receiving is not what I want.

In the Java application, the issuer is set as "https://sts.windows.net/%7Btoken%7D/" and this is what I receive when the first authentication happens and everything works file.

But when trying to refresh my token with v2.0, I receive "https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btoken%7D/v2.0" as issuer which Java does not accept. I tried using the V1.0 (since this is the version in the original token when the first authentication happens), but the token I received is missing half the data and also the signature. Because of this, java again does not accept this.

Do you have any solution to my problem?

This is the code inside my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
   {
      private string AccessToken { get; } = "access_token";
      private string RefreshToken { get; } = "refresh_token";
      private string IdToken { get; } = "id_token";
      public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
      {
         Configuration = configuration;
      }

      public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {

         services.AddAuthentication(options =>
         {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         })
         .AddCookie(o =>
         {
            o.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore();
            o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
               // this event is fired everytime the cookie has been validated by the cookie middleware,
               // so basically during every authenticated request
               // the decryption of the cookie has already happened so we have access to the user claims
               // and cookie properties - expiration, etc..
               OnValidatePrincipal = async x =>
               {
                  // since our cookie lifetime is based on the access token one,
                  // check if we're more than halfway of the cookie lifetime
                  var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                  var timeElapsed = now.Subtract(x.Properties.IssuedUtc.Value);
                  var timeRemaining = x.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value.Subtract(now);

                  if (timeElapsed > timeRemaining)
                  {
                     var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)x.Principal.Identity;
                     var accessTokenClaim = identity.FindFirst(AccessToken);
                     var refreshTokenClaim = identity.FindFirst(RefreshToken);
                     var idTokenClaim = identity.FindFirst(IdToken);

                     // if we have to refresh, grab the refresh token from the claims, and request
                     // new access token and refresh token
                     var refreshToken = refreshTokenClaim.Value;
                     var response = await new HttpClient().RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest
                     {
                        Address = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Configuration["AzureAd:TenantID"] + "/oauth2/token",
                        ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientID"],
                        ClientSecret = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"],
                        RefreshToken = refreshToken,
                        Scope = "openid profile offline_access email"
                     });

                     if (!response.IsError)
                     {
                        // everything went right, remove old tokens and add new ones
                        identity.RemoveClaim(accessTokenClaim);
                        identity.RemoveClaim(refreshTokenClaim);
                        identity.RemoveClaim(idTokenClaim);

                        identity.AddClaims(new[]
                        {
                           new Claim(AccessToken, response.AccessToken),
                           new Claim(RefreshToken, response.RefreshToken),
                           new Claim(IdToken, response.IdentityToken ?? idTokenClaim.Value)
                        });

                        // indicate to the cookie middleware to renew the session cookie
                        // the new lifetime will be the same as the old one, so the alignment
                        // between cookie and access token is preserved
                        x.ShouldRenew = true;
                     }
                  }
               }
            };
         })
         .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
         {
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Configuration["AzureAd:TenantID"];
            options.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientID"];
            options.CallbackPath = Configuration["AzureAd:CallbackPath"];
            options.SignedOutCallbackPath = Configuration["AzureAd:SignedOutCallbackPath"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
            //options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.Scope.Add("groups");

            // openid is already present by default: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/e98a0d243a7a5d8076ab85c3438739118cdd53ff/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L44-L45
            // adding offline_access to get a refresh token
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

            // we want IdSrv to post the data back to us
            options.ResponseMode = OidcConstants.ResponseModes.FormPost;

            // we use the authorisation code flow, so only asking for a code
            options.ResponseType = OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.Code;

            // when the identity has been created from the data we receive,
            // persist it with this authentication scheme, hence in a cookie
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            // using this property would align the expiration of the cookie
            // with the expiration of the identity token
            // UseTokenLifetime = true,

            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
               // that event is called after the OIDC middleware received the auhorisation code,
               // redeemed it for an access token and a refresh token,
               // and validated the identity token
               OnTokenValidated = x =>
               {
                  // store both access and refresh token in the claims - hence in the cookie
                  var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)x.Principal.Identity;
                  identity.AddClaims(new[]
                  {
                     new Claim(AccessToken, x.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken),
                     new Claim(RefreshToken, x.TokenEndpointResponse.RefreshToken),
                     new Claim(IdToken, x.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken)
                  });

                  // so that we don't issue a session cookie but one with a fixed expiration
                  x.Properties.IsPersistent = true;

                  // align expiration of the cookie with expiration of the
                  // access token
                  var accessToken = new JwtSecurityToken(x.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken);
                  x.Properties.ExpiresUtc = accessToken.ValidTo;

                  return Task.CompletedTask;
               }
            };
         });

         // Add framework services.
         services
             .AddControllersWithViews()
             // Maintain property names during serialization. See:
             // https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194
             .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

         // Application Insights
         services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

         services.AddMvc();

         // API - TT IMS Core
         services.AddSwaggerDocument();

         // Register Services
         services.AddScoped<IBookingService, BookingService>();
         services.AddScoped<IControllerService, ControllerService>();
         services.AddScoped<ILanguageService, LanguageService>();
         services.AddScoped<IMenuService, MenuService>();
         // API - TT.NETTools
         services.AddAllServices();
         services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
         services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);
         services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
         services.AddSession();

         // Add Kendo UI services to the services container
         services.AddKendo();
         services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING"]);
      }

      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
      {
         var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en-GB") };

         app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
         {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
         });

         SessionOptions sessOpts = new SessionOptions()
         {
            // Cookie = new CookieBuilder(),
            IdleTimeout = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0),
            IOTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
         };
         app.UseSession(sessOpts);

         if (env.IsDevelopment())
         {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
         }
         else
         {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
         }

         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
         app.UseStaticFiles();

         // TT Line API
         app.UseOpenApi();
         app.UseSwaggerUi3();

         app.UseRouting();

         app.UseAuthentication();
         app.UseAuthorization();

         app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
         {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
         });
      }
   }
```